# How to print an empty string in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I want to print an empty string like this one `""`, but erlang gives an empty list `[]`.

I tried with some options ~s, ~w from the io, io_lib modules and it doesnt work.

```
io_lib:format("~s",[""]).
```

-> `[[]]`

```
io_lib:format("~s",['']).
```

-> `[]`

```
io:format("~p",[""]).
```

-> `[]`

Can anyone show me the proper way to get `""` as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not pretty, but you need to put characters explicitly in case of an empty string. Does this work for you ?

```erlang
6> io:format("~s~n", [fun([]) -> "\"\"";(S) -> S end("")]).
""
ok
7> io:format("~s~n", [fun([]) -> "\"\"";(S) -> S end("\"non-empty string\"")]).
"non-empty string"
ok
8>
```

Answer (score 3):

It mostly depends on what you understand as *printing an empty string*.

In Erlang, an empty string is equivalent to an empty list. So, if you try to *just print it*, you'll get that:

```
1> AnEmptyString = "".
[]
2> io:format("~p~n", [AnEmptyString]).
[]
ok
```

If you want to print *the string* that is empty… well… since it's empty, it has no characters, therefore…

```
3> io:format(">~s<~n", [AnEmptyString]).
><
ok
```

So, if you want to just print two consecutive double quotes, you'll have to just do that *by hand*:

```
4> io:format("~s~n", ["\"\""]).
""
ok
```

Just keep in mind that you're not printing an empty string there, you're printing a string with just two double quotes ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

The Erlang don't have a type as string, please see a documentation - http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html. But if you want output something like `""`, you can try use character adaptation like `"\"\""` in `io` lib, but if you will try know the type of what you try output you will get the same type as list. Eg:

```erlang
1> [H|T] = io_lib:format("~p~n", ["\"\""]).
["\"\\\"\\\"\"",10]
is_list(H).
true
2>
```